# What are the application development tools in AiOps?

Tags: devops, agile, agile-project-management, teamwork-projects

I know the implementation structure of DevOps. I am reviewing and implementing AiOps.What are the practical tools in this field?

I want to research AI in CICD and ContinuesFeedback tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use One of the biggest takeaways in this report is the division of AIOps platform offerings into two categories:

```
Domain-agnostic
Domain-centric solutions
```

Gartner says that "requirements for increased flexibility for processing highly diverse datasets are having a significant impact on the market and shifting AIOps platforms toward domain-agnostic functionality." This is also being driven by the flexibility domain-agnostic platforms offer when it comes to ingesting increasingly diverse datasets across a progressive roadmap stretching from three to five years.

According to this link
[Devops Tools](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbestechcouncil/2021/09/10/which-aiops-tools-are-right-for-your-company/?sh=3b03bf39ef5f)

you Can  Read this report to learn: :

How AIOps can now deliver practical outcomes, rather than aspirational goals
Whether to adopt domain-centric and domain-agnostic AIOps based on use case, data diversity and roadmap
The different AIOps platform vendors and their range of capabilities

With that information as a backdrop, give BigPanda the opportunity to support your AIOps strategy.
BigPanda is the only domain-agnostic AIOps platform that delivers Event Correlation and Automation capabilities to accelerate your incident management lifecycle.

BigPanda works within your existing infrastructure, using BigPanda’s Open Integration Hub to ingest data from the broadest range of monitoring, observability, change and topology tools. BigPanda then applies Open Box Machine Learning to correlate and transform that data into actionable incidents. BigPanda’s Root Cause Analysis quickly helps operators identify which changes in infrastructure and applications are causing the incident.